# sql query join multiple tables on a case when column

Tags: sql, join

i have sql like this:

```
select case when.....end as colA, table2.col3
from table1
join table2 on table2.colB = colA
```

in the case when statement, there are some other tables columns, is this doable? I have got error saying that colA is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Column aliases are not understood in the `where` or `on` clauses.

You can do this with a subquery, assuming the `case` only involves columns from `table1`:

```
select case when.....end as colA, t2.col3
from (select table1.*, (case when.....end) as colA
      from table1
     ) t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.colB = t1.colA;
```

Otherwise, you *could* put the `case` statement in the `on` clause:

```
select case when.....end as colA, t2.col3
from (select table1.*, (case when.....end) as colA
      from table1
     ) t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.colB = ( case when.....end );
```